# What is causing the resistance?

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis, technical-analysis

The following is the chart for AAPL from Yahoo Finance. The chart says that the resistance level is $364.84. What is causing this resistance? Is it caused by big investors who have made a collective decision not to buy AAPL shares more?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resistance occurs when  supply is strong enough to stop a stock's upward movement. It's declared to be resistance when there are multiple touches of small price range without a significant  breakthrough of that price and each touch is followed by a modest retracement in price.